# Ruby stepping through decimals and casting to Array produces unexpected results

Tags: ruby

So.. I'm trying to refactor a piece of code, namely:

`v = [0.0, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.0]`

By using the `.step` method. Tried this but it's giving me some odd decimals for some of the numbers. Trying to figure out why this is?

`0.0.step(by: 0.1, to: 1.0).to_a`

Gives me this result:

`=> [0.0,
 0.1,
 0.2,
 0.30000000000000004,
 0.4,
 0.5,
 0.6000000000000001,
 0.7000000000000001,
 0.8,
 0.9,
 1.0]`

Ruby version: `2.3.0p0`

How can I go about figuring out why this is happening? Each of those numbers returns a float.

Comment: Thanks guys didn't realize this was answered already

Comment: `(0..10).map { |i| i.fdiv(10) }` would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Floats are inexact. Calculations (like adding) are more exact using Rationals. If you must use floats, convert to Floats after the calculations.

```
p 0.step(1, 1/10r).map(&:to_f) 3 =>[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
```

Comment: how did you answered it 8 mins ago if the question marked as duplicate 19 mins ago? o0

Comment: Didn't notice... it's locked now.

Comment: yea, but it was locked for more than 10 mins before you've answered, that's why I am curious of how you did it :D